# Deployed JavaFX Application with embedded JRE not startable on some systems

Tags: java, deployment, ant, javafx

The Application gets deployed via Java FX Packaging Tools and is bundled with the JRE (8u40, 32bit). The resulting Ant File was extended by us to run unit-tests and stuff like that. Since we want to support custom locations, we don´t use the generated FX-Installer. So the generated bundles/[appname] folder gets zipped and extracted on the target systems.  Usually the application runs fine, but on some systems we experience a weird issue.

When the user tries to start the application via generated .exe file, the application does not start. Nothing happens, no runtime errors, no system errors, just nothing at all. The same happens, when I try to start the .jar directly. Unfortunatly the clients have no rights to use the terminal, so I can´t launch the application from there.

The system, where this behavior occurs is Windows 7. For debugging purposes I added a simple Swing frame before starting the application, but this one isn`t starting either. No log-files where created, so I guess the application does not start at all.

Does anyone know if there is any chance to find out, what is going wrong during the start of the application and/or the runtime enviroment?

Comment: It would be easier to help when you provide any [mcve-project](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), some things fail because of typos or wrong configuration ;)

Comment: I am have the same issues and can find any kind of documentation.